# Table function omits bottom row

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am trying to make a confusion matrix for a logistic regression model and no matter what I do, the table function leaves out the bottom row. In terms of demonstrating my work, I can provide sample data below. My real data is very bulky and is downloaded onto my computer. However, the problem is that this simulation, which is based on my exact code, functions properly. The difference might be that this is a very small simulation. My real data has 20,000+ rows.

```
set.seed(1)
a<-runif(10)
b<-runif(10)
c<-rnorm(10)
sample_outcome<-sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=10)
sample.df<-data.frame(a,b,c,sample_outcome)
s_logistic <- glm(formula = sample_outcome~., data=sample.df, family=binomial)
s_probs <- predict(s_logistic, type="response")
s_predict <-rep(0,nrow(sample.df))
s_predict[s_probs>.5]=1
table(s_predict,sample.df$sample_outcome)
```

```
s_predict 0 1
        0 1 0
        1 2 7
```

In my actual data, the bottom row, the one that corresponds to "1,2,7" is ALWAYS missing. Any idea what might be going on here?

Comment: As is stands its a good example for why there is a specific close justification for debugging questions that are lacking crucial details. There's no way we can see your data. You have presented working code and then asked why its not working on your private data. And you are not asking for coding you are asking for guesses.

Comment: The command `table(x,y)` shows counts by the values of `x` as rows and by the values of `y` as columns.  If your `table()` output doesn't have a row for `x=1` then it's because none of your predictions are 1 (ie, `s_predict` is never equal to 1).